# How can i calculate average slope and length of slope of a multiple field farm in Arcmap 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, slope

I always calculate slope on farms i review with 2' contour lines.  Some fields are difficult since i need the average slope, but the field is rolling hills.  I usally take several slopes and take the average.  I want to have a way to do this in ArcMap 10.  Most farms have 6 - 10 fields and every field needs its individual slope (in degree) and slope length.

Comment: I think I get it but a picture of the data, and the analysis would help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using DEMs of the area.  I would start by obtaining or creating an outline shapefile of each farm field in question.  Use [Slope](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000v2000000.htm) to calculate the slope of the entire farm.  Then use [Zonal Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) (or [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/)) with MEAN as the statistic type, using the field outline shapes as the in_zone_data.  Each field will need a unique identifier.  This will calculate the average slope for each given area.

The same can be done for Slope Length as well.  However, more steps described [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~hmitaso/gmslab/reports/CerlErosionTutorial/denix/Models%20and%20Processes/RUSLE3d/ArcMap/ArcMap_computing_rusle_using_gis.htm) and [here](http://www.onlinegeographer.com/slope/hickey_slope_length.pdf) are required to generate the necessary raster.