# Extract angle of valley walls on both sides

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, slope, angles

I have a DEM of a the bedrock surface beneath a glacier and what I want to do is subtract the mean angle of the valley walls on the left and right side of the glacier along this line. I have a line that divides the glacier into a left and right side (the brown dotted points). Any suggestions on how to do it efficiently?

[image]

Comment: To start with, see if you can work with Zonal Statistics and the basic workflow described in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/how-can-i-calculate-average-slope-and-length-of-slope-of-a-multiple-field-farm-i) question (links are provided there)

Comment: Hi @JJ13! Did this work? how did you made it?

Answer (score 1):

a) Convert your raster line [to points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-point.htm), then [points to line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-points-along-a-line.htm).

b) [Buffer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) that line (the distance you are interested in) using left and right. Here you'll end up with two separate polygons (say, lineLeft and lineRight).

c) Using [Extract by Mask](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) (you must have the SpatialAnalist license), extract the DEM raster with lineLeft and lineRight. You'll end up with two rasters (say, demLeft and demRight).

d) Apply the [Slope](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm) tool to both rasters, and you'll have the slope angle on both sides (two new rasters will be created)

e) Then for each of the new rasters, check their [properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/setting-layer-properties.htm) and their stats will be under the 'Source' tab.